# Custom meta box not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I've created a custom meta box for a custom theme. The metabox appears but does not save any inputed values

```
<?php
/*
@ PACKAGE 3KTECHS THEME
=========================
CUSTOM POST TYPE  PAGE
=========================

*/

$contact = get_option('activate_contact');
if( @$contact == 1) {
   add_action('init','ktechs_contact_custom_post_type');

add_filter( 'manage_ktechs-contact_posts_columns','ktechs_set_contact_columns');
add_action( 'manage_ktechs-contact_posts_custom_column','ktechs_contact_custom_column', 10, 2);
add_action('add_meta_boxes','ktechs_contact_add_meta_box');
add_action('save-post','ktechs_save_contact_email_data');
}
/* custom contact cpt  */
function ktechs_contact_custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' =>'Messages',
        'singular_name' => 'Message',
        'menu_name' => 'Messages',
        'name_admin_bar' =>'Message',
    );
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' =>true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 26,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-email-alt',
'supports' => array('title','editor', 'author')
);
register_post_type('ktechs-contact',$args);
}
function ktechs_set_contact_columns( $columns ){
    $newColumns = array();
    $newColumns['title'] = 'Full Name';
    $newColumns['message'] = 'Message';
    $newColumns['email'] = 'Email';
    $newColumns['date'] = 'Date';
    return $newColumns;
}

function ktechs_contact_custom_column( $column, $post_id ){

    switch( $column ){

        case 'message' :
            echo get_the_excerpt();
            break;

        case 'email' :
            //email column

            $email = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_contact_email_value_key', true );
            echo $email;
            break;
    }
}
/*CONTACT META BOXES */
function ktechs_contact_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'contact_email', 'User Email', 'ktechs_contact_email_callback', 'ktechs-contact', 'side' );
}

function ktechs_contact_email_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'ktechs_save_contact_email_data', 'ktechs_contact_email_meta_box_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_contact_email_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="ktechs_contact_email_field">User Email Address: </label>';
    echo '<input type="email" id="ktechs_contact_email_field" name="ktechs_contact_email_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

function ktechs_save_contact_email_data( $post_id ) {

    if( ! isset( $_POST['ktechs_contact_email_meta_box_nonce'] ) ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ktechs_contact_email_meta_box_nonce'], 'ktechs_save_contact_email_data') ) {
        return;
    }

    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if( ! isset( $_POST['ktechs_contact_email_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['ktechs_contact_email_field'] );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_contact_email_value_key', $my_data );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a lot of code you've posted and the reason for the problem is pretty easy to fix (but hard to find).

You have this line in your code:

```
add_action('save-post','ktechs_save_contact_email_data');
```

But there is no hook called `save-post`. It should be `save_post`. So change the line above to

```
add_action('save_post', 'ktechs_save_contact_email_data' );
```

and it should work like a charm.

Comment: i had assumed I had a syntax error, mistype, or spelling error but could not find it. Thank you for your help it now works "like a charm'